# Minecraft forge not loading textures

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, intellij-14, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to teach myself java syntax and using minecraft as a platform for diving in.  I'm having a problem though because none of my textures are being loaded.  For that matter neither are my localizations.  Here is the code for my block

```
package net.richbaird.testtutorial.blocks;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
//import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.LanguageRegistry;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.richbaird.testtutorial.lib.constants;

public class OrangeBlock extends Block {
    private String blockName = "orangeBlock";
    public OrangeBlock() {
        super(Material.rock);
        this.setBlockName(constants.MODID + "_" + blockName);
        this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(this,blockName);
        this.setBlockTextureName(constants.MODID + ":" + blockName);
        //LanguageRegistry.addName(this,"tutorial block");

    }

}
```

here is my constants class

```
package net.richbaird.testtutorial.lib;
public class constants {
  public static final String MODID = "testtutorial";
  public static final String MODNAME = "Test Tutorial";
  public static final String VERSION = "1.0";
}
```

I have my texture saved at

```
~/IdeaProjects/testmod/src/main/resources/assets/testtutorial/textures/blocks/orangeBlock.png
```

According to the log it is unable to find my texture.  Here's the message I'm getting

```
[08:08:14] [Client thread/ERROR]: 
Using missing texture, unable to load 
testtutorial:textures/blocks/orangeBlock.png
java.io.FileNotFoundException: testtutorial:textures/blocks/orangeBlock.png
```

The client loads and my item shows up but with a default black and purple texture.  What have I done wrong?  I'm thinking it might have to do with my naming conventions, since the .lang file never gets read either, and the only way I can give my block a friendly name is with the now depreciated `LanguageRegistry.addName()` method

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For those who are curious, it's a bug with intellij 14 looks like.  Adding this line to the bottom of the build.gradle that comes with forge

```
sourceSets {
    main { output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir }
}
```

And running `gradle setupDecompWorkspace idea --refresh-dependencies`

fixed the problem.

Comment: On a Mac, bash gradlew setupDecompWorkspace idea --refresh-dependencies

Comment: I just wanted to update as of 2020, this still works for MC 1.12, and thank you so much! After hours of research this was the only solution that worked!

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this bug after updating IntelliJ, and while richbai90's solution did fix the immediate issue, it also broke compiling the mod into a jar (the assets folder gets included twice). After some digging around, I eventually found the root of the issue: IntelliJ was delegating the build task to Gradle, which put the assets and classes in separate folders, and Forge didn't know they belong to the same mod. The solution that worked for me was to build and run using the IDE, which is in the Settings dialog under *Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle* (the [help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#delegate_build_gradle) has more detailed instructions). On older versions of IntelliJ, this was called "Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle" (see the [help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.1/work-with-gradle-projects.html#delegate_build_gradle)).

Comment: This does not seem to solve the issue anymore.