# Minecraft Forge not loading resources

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

My problem is that when I start the game none of my resources are loaded. I use IntelliJ version 2021.2.2 and the 1.12.2 Minecraft Forge MDK version 14.23.5.2855 and I know that IntelliJ is the problem but all I found about this problem is this solution

```
sourceSets {
    main { output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir }
}
```

but that solution doesn't work anymore because `classesDir` is deprecated in Gradle version 4.9 and I don't know what to do anymore. My source code is available on my [GitHub](https://github.com/LeonHenning/MC-SAO-Core-Mod). Note: The problem is IntelliJ not how I added the resources because when I build the mod and use it in a normal Minecraft installation the resources are loaded. [debug.log](https://paste.ee/p/aEvr0)

Comment: Hi there, please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please give a minimal example and the source code excerpts, which could be the cause. Nobody can answer the question in this form without digging deeper into your project. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Please post your project in a github repo. It'll be easier to read then.

Comment: For future readers: This is the fix:  

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27624502/3875151

Answer (score 0):

After lots and lots of research, I finally found a way which is not deprecated. Add this to build.gradle

```
sourceSets.main.resources { srcDir 'src/generated/resources' }
```

or

```
sourceSets.main.resources { srcDir 'src/main/resources' }
```

Try this, and it should work. If it doesn't, I would recommend upgrading to 1.16.5 MDK or 1.17.1, because they're currently LTS

Comment: I tried both but both didn't work and I can't upgrade to 1.16.5 or 1.17.1 because I make this mod for a modded server that I'm working on with a few others and when I upgrade we need to upgrade the full modpack and a few of the mods are only available for the 1.12.2 and at this point I think that the problem is the forge version because I tried it in Eclipse and I had the same issue there so I think I will try an older Forge version

Comment: The problem isn't with Forge as I used to develop mods in 1.12.2 in Eclipse, and it worked properly. (Now I mod in 1.16.5), When you create a new world, click on more options and click on data packs, and see if an item called main resources is listed

Comment: Data packs don't exist in 1.12.2 they were added in 1.13 (17w43a)

Comment: Have you tried it in Eclipse (Because Eclipse is totally fine, I have worked with it), (Btw, delete unnecessary comments, the discussion is too long)

Comment: Yes I tried it in Eclipse and had the same problem

Comment: Hi, it's been 2 days, but I can still help :). Do one thing, when you run minecraft through your IDE, copy and paste the output from the console using https://pastebin.com or https://paste.ee

Comment: I added a link to the debug log

Comment: `Line 1132: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: cardinalsystem:models/item/ruby.json`, looks like I found the problem. It is not able to locate ruby.json file.

Comment: Of course, the file cannot be found if nothing is recognized or loaded from the resources folder