# Minecraft Forge assets not loading on Intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, minecraft-forge

I’m working on a Forge mod for Minecraft 1.12 on Intellij. Like a lot of people I ran into the issue of assets not being loaded when running the game from the IDE. All solutions that I tried have failed so far:

A lot of people have suggested to add the code below to build.gradle, but it raises an error because classesDir is deprecated; replacing it with classesDirs raises another error.

```
sourceSets {
    main { output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir }
}
```

I changed the “Build and run using” setting from “Gradle” to “Intellij IDEA” in *Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle* but I did not fix the problem either.

Additionally, when I try to build the jar, I get the following error:
`Entry assets/mccode/lang/en_us.lang is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set.` I don’t know what’s wrong here neither…

Here is the build.gradle script I’m using, as generated by Intellij:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // These repositories are only for Gradle plugins, put any other repositories in the repository block further below
        maven { url = 'https://maven.minecraftforge.net' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', name: 'ForgeGradle', version: '5.1.+', changing: true
    }
}

apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'

group = 'net.darmo_creations.mccode'
version = '1.0'

java {
    archivesBaseName = 'mccode'
    toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(8)
}

minecraft {
    // The mappings can be changed at any time and must be in the following format.
    // Channel:   Version:
    // snapshot   YYYYMMDD   Snapshot are built nightly.
    // stable     #          Stables are built at the discretion of the MCP team.
    // official   MCVersion  Official field/method names from Mojang mapping files
    //
    // You must be aware of the Mojang license when using the 'official' mappings.
    // See more information here: https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MCPConfig/blob/master/Mojang.md
    //
    // Use non-default mappings at your own risk. They may not always work.
    // Simply re-run your setup task after changing the mappings to update your workspace.
    mappings channel: 'stable', version: '39-1.12'

    // accessTransformer = file('src/main/resources/META-INF/accesstransformer.cfg')

    // Default run configurations.
    // These can be tweaked, removed, or duplicated as needed.
    runs {
        client {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            // The markers can be added/removed as needed separated by commas.
            // "SCAN": For mods scan.
            // "REGISTRIES": For firing of registry events.
            // "REGISTRYDUMP": For getting the contents of all registries.
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            // You can set various levels here.
            // Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                mc_code {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        server {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            // The markers can be added/removed as needed separated by commas.
            // "SCAN": For mods scan.
            // "REGISTRIES": For firing of registry events.
            // "REGISTRYDUMP": For getting the contents of all registries.
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            // You can set various levels here.
            // Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                mc_code {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Include resources generated by data generators.
sourceSets.main.resources { srcDir 'src/generated/resources' }

repositories {
    // Put repositories for dependencies here
    // ForgeGradle automatically adds the Forge maven and Maven Central for you

    // If you have mod jar dependencies in ./libs, you can declare them as a repository like so:
    // flatDir {
    //     dir 'libs'
    // }
}

dependencies {
    // Specify the version of Minecraft to use. If this is any group other than 'net.minecraft' it is assumed
    // that the dep is a ForgeGradle 'patcher' dependency, and its patches will be applied.
    // The userdev artifact is a special name and will get all sorts of transformations applied to it.
    minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.12.2-14.23.5.2854'

    // Real mod deobf dependency examples - these get remapped to your current mappings
    // compileOnly fg.deobf("mezz.jei:jei-${mc_version}:${jei_version}:api") // Adds JEI API as a compile dependency
    // runtimeOnly fg.deobf("mezz.jei:jei-${mc_version}:${jei_version}") // Adds the full JEI mod as a runtime dependency
    // implementation fg.deobf("com.tterrag.registrate:Registrate:MC${mc_version}-${registrate_version}") // Adds registrate as a dependency
    implementation "org.antlr:antlr4:4.9.3"

    // Examples using mod jars from ./libs
    // implementation fg.deobf("blank:coolmod-${mc_version}:${coolmod_version}")

    // For more info...
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html
}

// Example for how to get properties into the manifest for reading at runtime.
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes([
                "Specification-Title"     : "mc_code",
                "Specification-Vendor"    : "Darmo",
                "Specification-Version"   : "1", // We are version 1 of ourselves
                "Implementation-Title"    : project.name,
                "Implementation-Version"  : project.jar.archiveVersion,
                "Implementation-Vendor"   : "Darmo",
                "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        ])
    }
}

jar.finalizedBy('reobfJar')
```

What am I doing wrong? I don’t understand why Intellij is not capable of properly setting up Forge projects by itself…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an adjusted version that works on ForgeGradle 5/Gradle 7 (and will also work if you make source sets other than `main`):

```
sourceSets.all {
  it.output.resourcesDir = it.output.classesDirs.getFiles().iterator().next()
}
```

No need to downgrade to Gradle 4 or "build and run with intellij", this should just work™.

The *reason* `classesDir`-singular was removed is because Gradle now supports multiple JVM languages at the same time - your project might compile Java classes to `./build/classes/main/java` and Scala classes to `./build/classes/main/scala`, for example, so there might be more than one `classesDir`.

`classesDirs`-plural is a `FileCollection`, so you need to use `.getFiles()` to turn it into a `Set<File>`, then pick one arbitrarily with `.iterator().next()` - it doesn't matter which one you pick, all that matters is that resources end up in *some* directory that ends up on the classpath, because that's the only way Forge 1.12.2 knows how to load resources.

Answer (score 1):

So, I got it working finally… I had to downgrade Gradle from 7.3 to 4.9, redo what I already did (add `sourceSets { main { output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir } }`, set *Build and run using* to *Intellij IDEA*) and, most importantly, add a `pack.mcmeta` to the `resources` directory.

Comment: For future readers: This worked for me  

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27624502/3875151